# change color of a part of element in navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have a problem . i have a navbar with buttons like this:[image: you can see that active one!]

as you see , the active one has a blue background, but i want to make it like this when its active(notice that the bottom of button is blue too) :

[image: notice that bottom of the button is blue too now!!]

how would i do that? 
here is my code:

`<li class="nav-item selectable"><button>جزوات</button></li>`

should i add an span or something? or it could be done by pure css or js ??

thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not try, but something like this should work

```
.nav-item {
position: relative;
}
.nav-item:after {
content: '';
display: block;
height: 10px;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
right: 0;
color: blue;
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU SOOO MUCH MAN :D but its ```background-color: blue```